# Why is this sql line not working

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

It says that the command executed successfully but there are no values inserted into the organization table.

```
DECLARE @now DATETIME
SET @now = GETDATE()
DECLARE @numtoinsert INT
SET @numtoinsert = 100

DECLARE @counter INT
SET @counter = 101
WHILE @counter < @numtoinsert
BEGIN
SET @counter = @counter + 1

INSERT INTO [MVServices].[dbo].[Organization]
       ([Organization_Id]
       ,[Business_Number]
       ,[Legal_Name]
       ,[Common_Name]
       ,[Operating_As]
       ,[Sort_Name]
       ,[Effective_Date]
       ,[Expiry_Date]
       ,[Created_By]
       ,[Created_Date]
       ,[Last_Changed_By]
       ,[Update_Date])
 VALUES
       (@counter
       ,1234
       ,'ABC Construction'
       ,'ABC'
       ,'ABC Construction'
       ,'ABC Construction'
       ,@now
       ,null
       ,'seed'
       ,@now
       ,null
       ,null)

       END
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't insert anything because your `WHILE` condition is:

```
WHILE @counter < @numtoinsert
```

And 101 > 100, so it never enters the loop.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you insert records as long as `@counter < @numtoinsert`, and as `@counter` is 101, it's never smaller than `@numtoinsert` which is 100.

Answer (score 2):

You have two variables as follows:

```
SET @numtoinsert = 100
SET @counter = 101
```

The insert statement is then within a while loop:

```
WHILE @counter < @numtoinsert
```

counter is not greater than numtoinsert to begin with so the insert statement is not executed.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is incorrect:

```
SET @numtoinsert = 100
SET @counter = 101

WHILE @counter < @numtoinsert
```

You are saying:

```
WHILE 101 IS SMALLER THAN 100
```

This evaluates to false, so you never enter the while loop.